# Sorting a large array of objects causes the object fields to be blank

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, sorting

So I'm trying to import a large (52.2 MB) .csv file and sort the array of objects I create from it.  I have a set of functions that I call in the console because this is entirely for my own use, so there's lots of hard-coding and security problems but I'm the only one using it locally.

```
var allRows = null;
var headings = null;
var fullArray = [];
var file = "";

function grabFile() {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', './massive.csv');
    client.onload = function(e) {
    file  = client.responseText;
    eval('1 + 1');
    };
    client.send();
}
```

So I start by calling grabFile() which grabs the .csv file with over a million rows and a size of 52.2 MB.  I get an error, but it does what I want it to and gives me the file.

The error is:

XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: file:///pathto/massive.csv
Line Number 1, Column 1:

```
function createAllRows() {
    allRows = file.split(/\r?\n/);
    headings = allRows[0].split(',');
    allRows.shift();
}
```

I then call createAllRows() which separates the file into the rows, and puts the first row into a headings variable and the rest into an allRows variable.  This works fine.

```
function createFullArray() {
    for (var x = 0; x < allRows.length; x++) {
        fullArray[x] = {};
        for (var y = 0; y < headings.length; y++) {
            fullArray[x][headings[y]]=allRows[x].split(',')[y];
        }
        if (x % 10000 == 0) {
            console.log(x + ' rows completed!');
        }
    }
}
```

Now I call createFullArray() which creates an array of all the rows as objects with the headings as fields.  This also works fine, and tells me how many rows have been converted as it works.

```
function populatePartNumberBrandFamily() {
    for (var i = 0; i < fullArray.length; i++) {
        fullArray[i].part_number_brand_family = fullArray[i].part_number + ' ' + fullArray[i].brand_family;
    }
}
```

I call populatePartNumberBrandFamily() next, which just populates a specific field on each object in the array.  This works fine.

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.part_number_brand_family < b.part_number_brand_family)
        return -1;
    if (a.part_number_brand_family > b.part_number_brand_family)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

function sortArray() {
    fullArray.sort(compare);
}
```

I then call sortArray() which sorts fullArray by the field I populated.  This is where everything breaks, and all million+ objects in the array now have only blanks for the field values.

I'm not sure why this happens, or how to prevent it from happening.  I just need the array to be sorted by the field I populate so I can then find duplicates.

Comment: Does this only happen with a very large set of data? Have you tried with a smaller dataset? Have you verified the content of the array before sorting it?

Comment: It could also be that there is a memory limitation. With that size of data, you might be better off using _fetch_ and sort as you receive the chunks. Have you run browser developer tools to see how much memory your solution is using?

Comment: What are your plans with the duplicates? I think there are other ways of doing this if the end game is to get rid of duplicates. If you are looking to just get rid of duplicates then I would wait on sorting first. IE...create an obj with keys based on 'part_number_brand_family' or whatever your are looking for duplicates and create an object keys based on that. Duplicates will overwrite each other. Then you can worry about sorting if that's the end game.

Comment: I'm looking for duplicates in a specific field so I can determine whether a concatenation of other fields will lead to a unique ID I can use for something else.

And yes, I verified the content of the array before sorting, which is how I determined that the objects go blank after attempting a sort.

Comment: Rather than sorting the array, create a dictionary. When you read each item, check the dictionary to see if the specified field value is already there. If it isn't, then add it. If it is, then you have a duplicate.